# Updating a dataframe based on conditional values and grouping in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(database = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                         year1 = c(1994,1994,1996,2000,2002,2000,2003,2005,2003),
                         year2 = c(1994,1996,1998,2002,2002,2004,2003,2007,2006),
                         interval = c(0,2,2,2,0,4,0,2,3))
```

For every row where `interval=0` I want to change the value of `year2` so that it is the next highest value for the unique combination of `database` and `year1`, so that the updated dataframe looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(database = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                         year1 = c(1994,1994,1996,2000,2002,2000,2003,2005,2003),
                         year2 = c(1996,1996,1998,2002,2004,2004,2006,2007,2006),
                         interval = c(2,2,2,2,2,4,3,2,3))
```

I tried:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(database, year1) %>%
  mutate(year2 = ifelse(interval == 0, lead(year2), year2)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

And it works, but not perfectly, because it does not replace all the values in `year2`

Comment: If you're using `lead()`, note that this simply gives you the _previous_ value in a vector (like the `year2`).  If you want this previous value to also be the next _highest_, then you must sort (`dplyr::arrange()`) your `df` first.

Comment: Add `arrange(database, year1, year2)` after the first pipe

Comment: @starski  Remember in your `mutate()`, to do for `interval` what you do for `year2`: the `if_else()` and the `lead()`.  Otherwise, your output won't be identical to your `df1` sample.

Comment: In your desired output B suddenly have two observations of 2002

Comment: @Maël the ```arrange()``` does not seem to fix it

Comment: In df1, database == 3, year1 == 2003; year2 got assigned the highest value, how come?

Comment: @Chamkrai that is what I need to do, I need to code to check for all the intervals = 0, what is the database and year1 and find a matching pair for those and then assing the year2 of that pair to the line where interval=0

Comment: Why does row 6 year2 change from 2004 to 2002?

Comment: @AndreWildberg typo

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `lead` gives you the next value (ie. if you're in row 2 it gives you the value from row 3) of the chosen variable. Since you want the *greatest* value, you want to use `max` instead:

```
df %>%
    group_by(database, year1) %>%
    mutate(year2 = ifelse(interval == 0, max(year2), year2))

# A tibble: 9 × 4
# Groups:   database, year1 [6]
  database year1 year2 interval
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A         1994  1996        0
2 A         1994  1996        2
3 A         1996  1998        2
4 B         2000  2002        2
5 B         2002  2002        0
6 B         2000  2004        4
7 C         2003  2006        0
8 C         2005  2007        2
9 C         2003  2006        3
```

Since you've grouped the dataframe by "database" and "year", `max(year2)` will give you the greatest value from within that group, which is what you're looking for.